# CodeDeploy stuck on install step when deploying ECS service

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I'm trying to deploy ECS cluster service with CodeDeploy.

I have 2 containers `container-1`(listens 5001 port), `container-2`(listens 5002 port) in my ECS service(Both are the same except for the port) and uses EC2 launch type for ECS.

As I'd like to use Blue/Green deployment strategy, so configured ALB that has 2 listeners

- for 80 Port (100% weight for `container-1-target-group`, 0% weight for `container-2-target-group`)
- for 443 Port (100% weight for `container-1-target-group`, 0% weight for `container-2-target-group`)

and `container-1-target-group` has 5001 port and `container-2-target-group` has 5002 port. Both target groups have HEALTHY status on each port.

And here's my `appspec.yml`

```yaml
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "arn:aws:ecs:MY_REGION:MY_TASK_DEFINITION_WITH_CORRECT_VERSION"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "container-1"
          ContainerPort: 5001
        PlatformVersion: null
```

But I don't know why CodeDeploy stuck on install step. PRIMARY(blue) task set has 100% traffic but ACTIVE(green) task set has 0% and is waiting for 1 running state.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried strategies like CodeDeploy.AllAtOnce and 10PercentPer1Minute but both stuck on install step.